# Its possible use awk for create a extra field in column that count the position of line of table?

Tags: awk

for example in this file

```
a;b;c

a;b;v

a;b;f
```

and with the command output

```
a;b;c;1

a;b;v;2

a;b;f;3
```

please help me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this -

```
awk '{print $0,NR}' OFS=";" f
a;b;c;1
a;b;v;2
a;b;f;3
```